# How to use If Statement in Where Clause in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, if-statement, where-clause

I need to use if statement inside where clause in sql.

```
Select * from Customer
WHERE  (I.IsClose=@ISClose OR @ISClose is NULL)  
AND    
(C.FirstName like '%'+@ClientName+'%' or @ClientName is NULL )    
AND 
 if (@Value=2)
  begin
  (I.RecurringCharge=@Total  or @Total is NULL )    
  end
 else if(@Value=3)
begin
(I.RecurringCharge like '%'+cast(@Total as varchar(50))+'%' or @Total is NULL )  
end
```

Note: This is not the complete code. Everything is defined in SP. I have just written the code that was needed to understand the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [CASE Statement/Expression](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/14/sql-server-case-statementexpression-examples-and-explanation/)

```
Select * from Customer
WHERE  (I.IsClose=@ISClose OR @ISClose is NULL)  
AND    
    (C.FirstName like '%'+@ClientName+'%' or @ClientName is NULL )    
AND 
     CASE @Value
         WHEN 2 THEN (CASE I.RecurringCharge WHEN @Total or @Total is NULL) 
         WHEN 3 THEN (CASE WHEN I.RecurringCharge like 
                               '%'+cast(@Total as varchar(50))+'%' 
                     or @Total is NULL )
     END
```

Comment: i tried same but i gave me error "Incorrect syntax near '='" on this line 
when 1 then (I.RecurringCharge=@Total  or @Total is NULL )

Comment: Yeah it is giving the error at same location .i am already executing it in my original SP.

Comment: Again editted the code..Yes..because `I.RecurringCharge=@Total` is also an expression which should also be evaluated with `CASE WHEN` statement...@Asp_Newbie

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Customer
 WHERE (I.IsClose=@ISClose OR @ISClose is NULL)  
   AND (C.FirstName like '%'+@ClientName+'%' or @ClientName is NULL )    
   AND (isnull(@Value,1) <> 2
        OR I.RecurringCharge = @Total
        OR @Total is NULL )    
   AND (isnull(@Value,2) <> 3
        OR I.RecurringCharge like '%'+cast(@Total as varchar(50))+'%'
        OR @Total is NULL )
```

Basically, your condition was

```
if (@Value=2)
   TEST FOR => (I.RecurringCharge=@Total  or @Total is NULL )
```

flipped around,

```
AND (isnull(@Value,1) <> 2                -- A
        OR I.RecurringCharge = @Total    -- B
        OR @Total is NULL )              -- C
```

When **(A)** is true, i.e. @Value is **not** 2, [A or B or C] will become TRUE regardless of B and C results.  B and C are in reality only checked when `@Value = 2`, which is the original intention.

Answer (score 2):

Nto sure which RDBMS you are using, but if it is SQL Server you could look at rather using a [CASE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible
>   result expressions.
>
> The CASE expression has two formats:
>
> The simple CASE expression compares an expression to a set of simple
>   expressions to determine the result.
>
> The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean expressions to
>   determine the result.
>
> Both formats support an optional ELSE argument.

Comment: Then rather look at using a CASE statement

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from xyz where (1=(CASE WHEN @AnnualFeeType = 'All' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OR AnnualFeeType = @AnnualFeeType)
```