# Getting a Error in Switch Statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server, switch-statement

I am using SWITCH Statement in SP under Where Clause.Query Seems to be fine but i am unable to understand why it is giving me the error.
Query is:

```
Select * from Customer
WHERE  (I.IsClose=@ISClose OR @ISClose is NULL)  
AND    
(C.FirstName like '%'+@ClientName+'%' or @ClientName is NULL )    
AND 
 CASE @abc
         WHEN 2 THEN I.RecurringCharge=@Total or @Total is NULL
         WHEN 3 THEN I.RecurringCharge like 
                               '%'+cast(@Total as varchar(50))+'%' 
                     or @Total is NULL 
     END
```

The code is incomplete but sufficient to understand the problem.I am getting Below Error Message when trying to compile it.

```
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

The Error is on following line.

```
WHEN 2 THEN I.RecurringCharge=@Total or @Total is NULL
```

Please help me experts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The T-SQL `CASE` statement can **only** return (atomic) values (like 1, `Hello`) - not entire **code blocks** or expressions...

Comment: but this is my requirment to return like above based on @abc.
Can i fix it somehow ,or there is no solution for it ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do - in the middle of your `WHERE` clause, you're trying to assign variables and stuff.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use If Statement in Where Clause in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171748/how-to-use-if-statement-in-where-clause-in-sql)

Comment: @Asp_Newbie I would suggest going back to your unresolved problem and **UNMARKING** it as accepted.  It is going to mislead visitors to the page.  Also look at my answer on that question for rephrasing your query. Actually, you should list some rows of data and the expected results to be **absolutely** clear what logic you are after.

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation of the CASE sattement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Instead `CASE <variable> WHEN <value> ...` you should use `CASE WHEN <variable>=<value> ...`.

In your case, you'd be better off not useng `CASE` at all. Try rewriting the conditions like this instead

```
Select * from Customer
WHERE  (I.IsClose=@ISClose OR @ISClose is NULL)  
AND    (C.FirstName like '%'+@ClientName+'%' or @ClientName is NULL )    
AND    (@Total is NULL OR
            (
                (@abc = 2 and I.RecurringCharge=@Total)
                OR
                (@abc = 3 and I.RecurringCharge like '%'+cast(@Total as varchar(50))+'%')
            )
        )
```

I indented the conditions just to make it clear how they are applied. I also factored out the common `OR @Total is NULL` condition.